# How to use AWS SSL certificate in free tier?

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have hosted the application on AWS using free tier and now I want to have the application running securely using Amazon SSL certification but what I come to know that I have to use Route 53 which I think is not eligible for free.

Can it possible to use Amazon SSL certificate without spending any money?

I know how to configure with Let's Encrypt in nginx but not sure with Amazon SSL certificate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only use certificates issued by Amazon Certificate Manager on Amazon services that are integrated with ACM: ELB, CloudFront, ElasticBeanstalk, API Gateway, and CloudFormation.  CloudFormation can only leverage ACM certificates for the four services listed before it.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/acm-services.html

Answer (score 0):

https://aws.amazon.com/free/  Read their documentation and contact AWS sales.

To try a thing, just do it. If you don't like the costs, delete it and pursue a less expensive option.